# Removing items from list not removing them from RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I remove an itemfrom my list, it does not get removed from the RecyclerView at all.

Here is how I remove (*user.getUid() does equal dataSnaphot.getkey()*):

```
for(User user: mFriendList){
    if(user.getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey())){
        mFriendList.remove(user);
    }
}
friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My User object gets removed from the list but not from the view. When I use the same method for adding itemsto the list, like..

```
mFriendList.add(user);
friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

..it does get added to the list and view as well. Why is it not working well with removing from the list?

**EDIT:**

Setting up RecyclerView (inside a Fragment):

```
mRecyclerView = (EmptyRecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactRecyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

View myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.emptyAdapterList);
mRecyclerView.setEmptyView(myView);

mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

mFriendList = new ArrayList<User>();

friendAdapter = new FriendAdapter(mFriendList, getContext());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(friendAdapter);
```

Comment: Please add more detailed code(how to set your adapter etc.)

Comment: @oguzhand added it under edit, check please. Anything more I should add??

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from collection in foreach loop. It may cause undefined behavior depending on the collection. Try using iterator.

Comment: Ok I will look into that, thanks for the suggestion @tommus

Comment: Short of an exception being thrown (maybe because of removing an item while you are iterating over it as pointed out by @tommus) it seems like mFriendsList might have been re-intialized to a different ArrayList or mRecyclerView received a new Adapter?  Without seeing more code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @MichaelKrause What more code would you need me to add here?

Comment: @Carlton are you sure about "mFriendList.remove(user);" is called? If getUid() or getKey() return variable types are different(for example String and int) compiler does not give an error but code will not work as you wanted.

Comment: @oguzhand yes I am sure. I did as tommus suggested and it works fine, it was probably a problem caused by using the for loop

Comment: @tommus I tried using an Iterator instead and it seems to be working just fine, thanks! If you want you can answer this question so I can upvote & accept

Comment: @MichaelKrause Thanks for the input, it works fine by using an iterator instead as suggested by tommus

Comment: Which means a ConcurrentModificationException was being thrown.  Logcat output would have helped.

Comment: Try to LOG success message if it enters in IF statement or not

Comment: Use Iterator to remove elements from list while iterating a list.

Comment: @MichaelKrause weirdly enough I can't see any exceptions being thrown in my logs?

Comment: @LakshayJain I solved it by using iterator, thanks!

Comment: @shalini yes it was suggested earlier, I tried and it works. Thanks for input!

Comment: @Carlton Is the code you are calling in a try/catch block where you are eating runtime exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing items in foreach loop may cause undefined behavior depending on the collection.

Instead of calling `remove` method directly while iterating over collection You have four options:

- use [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
final Iterator<User> iterator = mFriendList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    final User user = iterator.next();
    if(user.getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

- create another collection, collect all items that you'd like to remove and then [removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) items:

```
final Collection toRemove = new ArrayList<User>();
for(User user: mFriendList){
    if(user.getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey())){
        toRemove.add(user);
    }
}
mFriendList.removeAll(toRemove);
```

- use Java 8 (or Stream Support) Streams API, especially filter() method:

```
mFriendList = mFriendList.stream()
    .filter(user -> !user.getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- use RxJava (or RxJava 2) filtering:

```
mFriendList =  Single.just(mFriendList)
    .flatMapIterable(identity()) // list -> list
    .filter(user -> !user.getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey()))
    .toList()
    .blockingGet(); // or whatever transformation
```

Depends on whether you are using reactive approach or not I strongly recommend to use the latest one for consistency or just to remove dependencies from Stream Support libraries if you are targeting old enough Android SDK.

Keep in mind you have to `notifyDataSetChanged()` as soon as you will finish your modifications.

Comment: Thanks again! I will also try with lambda since I need to use it more :)

Comment: I have added code samples, including reactive approach. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thank you for the samples, very helpful! I was wondering, how do I enable Java8 use? When I try to use it, I get this error "usage of API documented as @since 1.8+..." and I could not find a way in settings to enable it?

Comment: It all depends on which Android SDK you are targeting. You have few options: use Java 8 for SDK level 20 and newer, use Jack and Jill compiler (I strongly recommend not), use supporting libraries (Stream Support and Retrolambda to get at least some Java 8 features), forget about Java 8 for now and use RxJava2 which allows you to use API similar to Java 8 Streams. In most cases you will be forced to use multiple of above hints at once (eg. Retrolambda with RxJava for old SDKs). Take a look at [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html).

Comment: I target 25 and min is 24, and then I add compileOptions (from the article) it throws an error and tells me that it does require Jack. Do I have to use Jack ?

Comment: No. Ensure You have disabled Jack and set source compatibility with Java 8. Please follow the instructions from the link I posted above.

Comment: Okay, I did and it works now, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited info provided by your code my best guess would be that your removal fails since your data source is unaffected by your removed item from the list. If that's not it provide more code and I' wld be happy to help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was problem by using for-loop instead of iterator.